# Go Concurrency Pattern- will this leave hanging goroutines?

Tags: go, goroutine

In Rob Pike's [Google IO talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs) on Go Concurrency Patterns, he presented [this code](http://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#48) as an example of how to pick the fastest responder from a number of replica servers:

```
func First(query string, replicas ...Search) Result {
    c := make(chan Result)
    searchReplica := func(i int) { c <- replicas[i](query) }
    for i := range replicas {
        go searchReplica(i)
    }
    return <-c
}
```

**Question**: Won't this leave N-1 of the replica goroutines blocking on a channel write?

In the discussion after the talk, one of the audience members seems to be asking this question, but got kind of a handy-wavy response.

I'd be inclined to change the 3rd line to something like this:

```
searchReplica := func(i int) {
   select {
      case c <- replicas[i](query):
      default: // non-blocking write
 }
}
```

Comment: Or `make(chan Result, len(replicas))`. If you don't just want to let the other goroutines run to completion and then get cleaned, but instead want a way to ask them to die, look at the [context package](https://blog.golang.org/context).

Comment: Error handling is also missing, since queries may fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. But that doesn't fit on a single slide. He was talking about concurrency patterns, not necessarily the code to do it.

Of course, I still wouldn't have put that code on a slide...

Comment: I agree about not putting it on a slide. I actually asked this question because of a bug in my code, based on a misapprehension of how channels are supposed to work. Seeing the slide made me think it *ought* to be correct!